# dbt debug on tutorial producing semaphore issue

Tags: python, dbt

In attempting to walk through the GitHub [tutorial](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/jaffle_shop) with Snowflake as the warehouse, I encounter the following error when running "dbt debug":

```
Running with dbt=0.15.0
dbt version: 0.15.0
python version: 3.7.5
python path: /usr/local/Cellar/dbt/0.15.0_1/libexec/bin/python3.7
os info: Darwin-19.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
Using profiles.yml file at /Users/David*****/.dbt/profiles.yml

Configuration:
profiles.yml file [OK found and valid]
dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
profile: jaffle_shop [OK found]
target: dev [OK found]

Required dependencies:

git [OK found]
Connection:
account: XXXXXXXX
user: XXXXXXX
database: TEST_DB
schema: jaffle_shop
warehouse: LOAD_WH
role: SYSADMIN
client_session_keep_alive: False
***zsh: abort dbt debug
/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py:144: UserWarning: semaphore_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphores to clean up at shutdown
len(cache))***
```

What is this and how should I fix?

Comment: Also having the same issue myself

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this via Google, I followed the solution shared here from the dbt slack over @ getdbt.slack.com

```
    brew update & brew upgrade & brew install openssl

    # copy libssl.1.0.0.dylib and libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib from 
    # /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/<opensslversion> to /usr/lib/
    # (note: your version of these files may be different depending on your openssl version)
    cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/<opensslversion>/
    # the exact names of the files here may be slightly different
    sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
    # make a softlink libssl.dylib and libcrypto.dylib
    sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib
    sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```

src: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119429#386843

Comment: That first line should probably be `brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl`, otherwise you end up trying to run all 3 commands in parallel and confusion ensues...